# get jacoco coverage results in jenkins pipeline in a variable to use as needed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco, slack

I have a project where I need to show jacoco's coverage data on slack and mail . So I need a way to get the data without parsing the files if possible ,the way it shows in the console output .Any help would be appreciated .